# Spring Data - Page Request - order by function

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement pagination in Java application based on Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.2.16.Final.

I have a following code:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, new Sort(new Order(Direction.DESC, "name"))
Page page = myRepository.findAll(specification, pageRequest);
```

and everything works fine. However now I would like to order by sql function value, for example: `ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name)`.

It works perfectly when I input such clause in `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`, for example:

```
public class MyRepository {
  @Query("select e from MyEntity e order by CHAR_LENGTH(e.name)")
  public List<MyEntity> findAllOrderedByNameLength();
}
```

unfortunately I am not able to do it with PageRequest. When I pass: `ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name)` to PageRequest as a property:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, new Sort(new Order(Direction.DESC, "ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name)"))
Page page = myRepository.findAll(specification, pageRequest);
```

the following exception is being thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property CHAR found for type MyEntity!
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make a view in the db?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works in query is that Hibernate passes whatever it doesn't recognize directly into SQL, it isn't a JPA feature so it probably wouldn't work with some other provider.

One nice option is to implement a custom `Order` class, and use that instead. You can find detailed instructions in [this blog](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/). With the exact implementation as in the blog, you would use it as `OrderBySqlFormula.sqlFormula("CHAR_LENGTH(name) desc")`

**UPDATE**

The proposed solution is for Hibernate only, can't be used with Spring Data code, which expects `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order` and not `org.hibernate.criterion.Order`.

Comment: OK, but it requires "Criteria" object which I do not have reference to. In my code only "Specification" and "PageRequest" are passed to repository and it works really nice because it returns "Page" object which I need to return to the client (it contains total number of elements and total number of pages). In your example I would need to implement such logic from scratch - first count, then select and set everything to Page object.

Comment: You don't need a reference to `Criteria`. If you are referring to method `toSqlString()`, it is declared in `org.hibernate.criterion.Order` and is used internally.

Comment: You would use it like this `new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, new Sort(OrderBySqlFormula.sqlFormula("CHAR_LENGTH(name) desc")))`

Comment: OK, but the problem is that I need to pass `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` to my repository, which requires `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` which I am not able to build because I do not have `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order`. I only have `org.hibernate.criterion.Order` which is incompatible.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry. I saw the `hibernate` tag and totally forgot that this is a spring data question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Formula and define a custom field for the CHAR_LENGTH(name) expression and use it for ordering

See for example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation)

Comment: Sounds interesting. However, is it possible to create such formulas dynamically when needed? The problem is that name of the sorting property ("name" in this case) comes from client. The only thing I need to  do is to wrap this property name with function call and pass to repository. There are multiple entities and multiple possible sorting columns, so it could be problematic to maintain formula property for each of them.

Comment: Also, there is a bug in Hibernate that has been there for 10 years when using @Formula in your Entities. It probably won't show up in the use case you are using it in, but in your other native queries that try to convert to this entity, you will have the error.