# spring data domain.Pageable : sort with calculated property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity and i'm using Pageable and I want to sort by a calculated property.
here is my entity:

```
public class Task extends Entity implements Serializable {

  @JsonView(Views.Simple.class)
  private long startTime;

  @JsonView(Views.Simple.class)
  private long endTime;
}
```

In the repository I have :

```
Page<Task> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

And in the service I want to sort by

> endTime - StartTime

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please also add what you have tried so far and what did not work about this. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA - Is it possible to sort on a calculated property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139985/spring-data-jpa-is-it-possible-to-sort-on-a-calculated-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370215/ordering-results-by-computed-value-in-hibernate

Comment: thanks @Michal, this is a good solution but i don't want that the computed value to be persisted in the database.
I added the @Transient annotation but, an exception is raised : 
`Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [runTime] on this ManagedType`