# JPA domain.Sort based on content of json column?

Tags: mysql, json, sorting, jpa

I have a column defined as follows:

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "ex_data")
@JsonProperty
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
private T exData;
```

Where, given type T, I can store a variety of basic JSON objects in my table, like so:

```
{
  "active": true,
  "color": "red",
  "flavor": "cherry"
}
```

If I want to created a sorted, paginated, query against the table, is it possible to use the content of the JSON for the Sort object?

i.e. an equivalent to this, which presently does not work:

```
 Sort sort = Sort.by("exData.color").ascending();
```

Comment: does one of the options provided as part of the answer help resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not directly supported by JPA.

One way would be to use a native SQL function to access a specific property nested inside the json column.

Unfortunately, native expressions are not supported when using `Sort`, which only accepts entity properties to order by.

---

**Solution 1**: native query with json key parameter and pagination

```
@Repository
public interface JsonSortNativeRepositoryMySql extends JpaRepository<JsonSortNativeEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM json_sort_native_entity ORDER BY "
                    // flexibly extract the sort value from json:
                    + "my_json_column->> :sortKey" //
                    + " DESC", //
                    countQuery = "select count(*) from json_sort_native_entity", //
                    nativeQuery = true)
    Page<JsonSortNativeEntity> findSortedNative(Pageable pageable, @Param("sortKey") String sortKey);
}
```

The corresponding pageable is created without Sort parameter, and the sort key can be dynamically supplied when calling the native query method:

```
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20); // first page with 20 entries
var pageResult = repository.findSortedNative(pageable, "$.color");
```

---

**Solution 2**: [sort by computed attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139985/spring-data-jpa-is-it-possible-to-sort-on-a-calculated-property)

Another option would be to specify a computed attribute value using a Hibernate `@Formula` as part of the `Entity`:

```
@Formula("my_json_column->>'$.color'") // <-- fixed key "color" to extract from json column
private String formulaValue;
```

This way, a normal `Sort` can be used:

```
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by("formulaValue").descending());
var pageResult = repository.findAll(pageable); // standard JpaRepository method
```

However, the key to extract the sort values is fixed in this case (possible alternative: [Spring Data - Page Request - order by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624815/spring-data-page-request-order-by-function))

MySQL JSON reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html